# How to validate existing invalid model via nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

It seems Rails will only validate an existing invalid nested model if the nested model's attributes have changed.

With the following models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  validates_presence_of :street
end
```

The following code for example, will save and return true:

```
p = Person.first
p.update_attributes({:first_name => "Bryan", :addresses_attributes=>{"0"=>{:street=>"", :id => 1}})
```

Is there a way to validate the nested model as if it's attributes have changed? ( while retaining errors )

Comment: Use the `save` or `save!` methods.  `update_attributes` is for special cases, and (I would have to look but) think it doesn't trigger certain checks that the straight-up `save` methods do.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me -- here's a test-case I created to prove it

```
require 'test_helper'

class PersonTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "update address" do
    expected_new_address="pandascout"
    person = Person.create(name: "jwo")
    address = person.addresses.create(street: "123 Elm")

    person.update_attributes({:addresses_attributes=>{"0"=>{:street=>expected_new_address, :id=>address.id}}})
    assert_equal expected_new_address, person.addresses.first.street
  end
end
```

The only thing I can think of is you have a reference to "address" and you need to reload it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer and create this test.

Comment: @deadkarma sure -- I was curious and this was a way we could both reproduce the results... Did you find what you were looking for with this question? If so, please mark as accepted -- if not, let me know and I can dive further into.

Comment: I created a fresh new app, and it validates the nested model just fine. I reverted to a much earlier commit in my app, and it worked there as well. So it must be some change between now and 6 months ago :/

Comment: I think I found the crux of the problem. If the nested model hasn't `changed?` it doesn't run validations on it, thus allowing the parent model to update without errors. In your test-case, you are updating the street attribute on a valid address model.

Comment: So you want to run validations against a model that didn't change?

Comment: I suppose I'm trying to figure out how to run validations on the existing, invalid nested models through the Person. Ideally using the typical or similar controller convention: `@person.update_attributes(params[:person])`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9410/discussion-between-deadkarma-and-jesse-wolgamott)